# MVC 3 - using reflection to choose a partial view - abuse?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I think I'm finally starting to get MVC 3, but if someone can validate this approach I'd feel better about it.

I have a website, let's say, and I have models for `NormalPage` and `EventPage`.  `EventPage` has an `EventDate`, but that's the only difference, and let's just say that `EventPage` inherits from `NormalPage` if that makes life easier.

Two views handle these two (slightly) different models, one just showing the page, and the other displaying the date and showing a registration form.  They have different designs, so different views are in order.

All the tutorials will say "yup, now write two Controllers: Events and Pages".  That seems silly - both are just passing the model to a (appropriate) view.  I can use a single "Page" controller and choose the appropriate view using reflection, right?  `typeof(Model)`, once I've pulled the data from the database, can tell me whether or not I should pull the `Event` view or the `Page` view.

Is that dumb, or asking for trouble, or misusing the framework?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What do you intend to do with reflection?  You don't need to do anything like that to return views dynamically.  From any controller action, you can return `View("EventView", eventModel)` or `View("NormalView", normalModel)` and it will return that view.

On a different note, I'm not sure what tutorials suggested that it's typical to have one view per controller but it's not.  It's typical to have several views and actions in one controller.